# How to access map in velocity template file

Tags: java, velocity

when I passed a `Map<String,String>` in velocity template file, and when try to print the values of map it get sorted (on the basis of ASCII values).

I am doing as follows:

this is my velocity template file::

```
#set($tocList=${mapReference.mapValue})
#set($tocEntry="")

<div >
 #foreach($tocEntry in $tocList.keySet())
  <a href="#$tocEntry">$tocList.get($tocEntry)</a><br/>
 #end
</div>
```

My Java code is :

```
 Map<String, String> map=new HashMap<String, String>();
 Map<String,HashMap> m1=new HashMap<String, HashMap>();

   \\values that we want to print in template file

   map.put("sdfhfg", "Df lm"); 
   map.put("chdgfhd", "gBc Jk");
   map.put("dghjdhdf", "gI Ml");

   m1.put("mapValue", (HashMap) map);

  VelocityEngine velocityEngine = VelocityEngineFactory.getVelocityEngine();
  VelocityContext context = new VelocityContext();
  context.put("img",model);
  context.put("mapReference",m1);
  context.put("iterator", new IteratorTool());


  Template t = velocityEngine.getTemplate("tocTemplate.vm");
  StringWriter writer = new StringWriter();
    t.merge(context , writer);
    System.out.println(writer);
```

Output is:

```
 <div>
   <a href="#dghjdhdf">gI Ml</a><br/>
   <a href="#chdgfhd">gBc Jk</a><br/>
   <a href="#sdfhfg">Df lm</a><br/>
 </div>
```

Why these values get sorted? I want to print map as it is.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The order of the HasMap will not remain constant over time, from [Javadoc](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html):

> This class makes no guarantees as to the order of the map; in
>   particular, it does not guarantee that the order will remain constant
>   over time.

To remain the order, you can consider use [LinkedHashMap](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/LinkedHashMap.html) as following suggested:

> This linked list defines the iteration ordering, which is normally the
>   order in which keys were inserted into the map

Comment: doesn't the [link](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/TreeMap.html)